# Can I replace a reference to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Ubuntu to read all the contents from our server

Tags: css, html, layout, razor

I am working on a web layout template which I have downloaded, and I noted on some CSS files there are references to external links to load fonts and themes, such as the following line of code at the beginning of a .css file:-

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Ubuntu)
```

When I open the link inside my browser I noted it will load the following:-

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Karla'), local('Karla-Regular'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/karla/v2/azR40LUJrT4HaWK28zHmVA.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Ubuntu'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ubuntu/v4/_xyN3apAT_yRRDeqB3sPRg.woff) format('woff');
}
```

My problem is that I am using this template for our intranet, so users might access the intranet even if they do not have access to the internet. So my question is how I can add these fonts and themes inside my asp.net mvc project , so that the contents will be loaded from our server and not from Google site ?
Thanks ?

**EDIT**
I replaced the following :-

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Ubuntu);
```

with :-

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Karla'), local('Karla-Regular'), local('/Content/fonts/azR40LUJrT4HaWK28zHmVA.woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Ubuntu'), local('/Content/fonts/_xyN3apAT_yRRDeqB3sPRg.woff');
}
```

but i did not get the font effect ?
BR

Answer (score 2):

You may want to see [this section](https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#Download_Fonts) from the Google FAQ on the subject

> **Can I download the fonts on Google Fonts to my own computer?** 
>   Yes. To
>   download the fonts, simply add fonts to your collection and click the
>   "Download your Collection" link. You can download the fonts to use
>   them for your mockups, in your documents or to host them on your own
>   server.

[This article](http://ruel.me/blog/2011/02/03/using-google-fonts-locally/) goes into further step by step detail about how to do this, it should solve any issue with end users not having access to the internet- as long as you're local references to the fonts are correctly defined in your CSS.

Comment: but currently the downloaded fonts from google has .woff extension,, so does this format supported b IE, firefox, chtrome ??

Answer (score 1):

You should download the font from the Google site, then process it with a font file generator like the [FontSquirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), which also produces a CSS file you can use.

The point is that different browsers need different font formats, served using a suitably crafted `@font-face` rule.

When you use the fonts using a URL like https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Ubuntu, the Google server recognizes the browser and sends just CSS code tailored for that browser. If you just copy that onto your page, it will only work on that browser and sufficiently similar browsers.

Comment: so what is the best approach to follow, so that i add the fonts locally and work on all browsers?

Comment: After generating the font files, upload them onto the intranet HTTP server and refer to them with relative URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can self-host Google Fonts, read Self-host web fonts quick guide:
https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/using_type/self_hosting_web_fonts

Here you can find a practical example of how this can be done:
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_icons

Setup Method 1. Using via Google Fonts - provides an example of how the Google Material Icons font can be used via fonts.googleapis.com.

Setup Method 2. Self hosting - provides an example of how the same Google Material Icons font can be self hosted.